# OnClick event of Input radio always returns true at first click

Tags: jquery

I am using Input radio.

it should check uncheck by clicking on it.

if i implement OnClick event it gives me Checked=true at first click but it should return false.

if i implement OnMouseDown event of radio then at first click it returns false as expected.

what is the problem regarding the onclick event.

i want to use Onclick event of radio.

i am using radio control not checkbox n second thing is for using prop i have to use any specific version .js file pls mention that.

Comment: Use `checkbox` not `radio` to `uncheck`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to check the `checkbox checked property` like,

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tSSgr/)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly use the `change` event for full accessibility compatibility - some people are forced to use a keyboard only, so the click event would never fire. Secondly you can use `is(':checked')` to test.

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/en7AQ/)